# jQuery coda slider effect navigation stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, coda-slider

I'm using the Coda Slider effect described here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/  . It works perfectly but I need one more feature added and I don't know how to achieve this: I want the navigation to stop at the last and first tabs. I want the left/right button to disappear or became inactive if I am at the first/last tab.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in the scroll options section of this code you need to add

**cycle: 'false',**

The documentation on serialScroll says if cycle is set to true, "the first element will be shown after going over the last, and the other way around." Setting to false *should* disable this behavior without having to manual disable your buttons.